# using iteration instead of recursion in searching in a binary search tree

Tags: java

I was reading about searching items in a binary search tree. I found this code :

```
public class Node {
         public int key;
         public Object data;
         public Node left;
         public Node right;
        }

public static Object search(Node root, int key) {
     if (root == null)
     return null;
     else if (key == root.key)
     return root.data;
     else if (key < root.key)
     return searchTree(root.left, key);
     else
     return searchTree(root.right, key);
     }
```

I want to rewrite the search() method so that it uses iteration instead of
recursion. I did like this :

```
public static Object search(Node root, int key) {
         if (root == null)
         return null;
         else if (key == root.key)
         return root.data;
         else if (key < root.key) {
             Iterator iter = root.left.iterator();
         while (iter.hasNext()) {
             object item = iter.next();
             if(iter.key.equals(key)) {
                 return item.data;
             }
         }
         } else {
             Iterator iter = root.right.iterator();
             while (iter.hasNext()) {
                 object item = iter.next();
                 if(iter.key.equals(key)) {
                     return item.data;
                 }
             }
         }
    }
```

Am I doing right?

Thanks

Comment: Did that pass compilation? Using iteration doesn't mean using Iterator interface.

Comment: I did not implement all the code so that I can do the compilation ... I just have the code for search method no more .. Do you think I did correct? thanks

Comment: i don't get this line of code- `Iterator iter = root.left.iterator();`. how you got iterator from `Node` object. And what Iterator#next will return if you implement in future

Comment: No, I don't think so

Comment: @Subhrajyoti Majumdern I was just trying to learn myself , the code could be totally wrong , I do not know .. if you can correct my code so do that please ,, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Frankly say - I pretty much lost on your iterator approach, as non recursive approach you can use a stack.

1. Push root into stack.
2. Pop element from stack and check you search criteria of a node(no element in stack break, search failed).
3. Criteria matched, break.
4. Criteria does not match push left and right child into stack.
5. Go back to step 2.